# uninitialized constant ActionController::Routing (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-deployment, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am getting this error when trying to deploy my application on a linux server.

Versão servidor: PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (Gentoo 4.8.1-r1 p1.2, pie-0.5.7) 4.8.1, 64-bit

```
    uninitialized constant ActionController::Routing (NameError)
  /home/divulgapocos/apps_rails/divulgapocos/config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /home/divulgapocos/apps_rails/divulgapocos/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /opt/apx_passenger//helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /opt/apx_passenger//helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /opt/apx_passenger//helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /opt/apx_passenger//helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /opt/apx_passenger//helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'devise'
gem 'pg'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'paypal-recurring'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'railties'
gem 'rack'


group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've updated this app from an older, 2.x version of Rails. You have a line in your `config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb` that uses the `ActionController::Routing` constant, that constant no longer exists in Rails 4.2.

So, basically, the fix here is to upgrade your app to 4.2 properly. I could tell you to remove the `ActionController::Routing` line from your file, but probably that's just one of many other issues you haven't fixed here.

The weird thing here is that you haven't mentioned having the same problems in dev, which suggests you're not actually using the version of Rails in dev that you think you are.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually, my app was created on rails 4.2.1. The server's rails was 2.x and then they changed to 4.2.1. This new_rails_defaults.rb was created by the server when I created the app on their control painel.

Comment: Ok, so that explains why you didn't have the problem in dev, but it's the same solution for your issue.

Comment: I think I have the same problem. I've built an app on 2.7.0 but my server is 2.6.1 so I did a downgrade.  Works fine locally but I get the same kind of error message on the server.  Any idea on how to fix it ?