# How to get the layout of a particular path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to figure out how to get the layout of a particular path.  I know that I can get the layout of the current page with the following:

```
(controller.send :_layout).inspect.split("/").last.gsub(/.html.erb/,"")
```

But what if I want to get the layout of this path: `companies_edit_path`?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
controller_name =
  Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('companies_edit_path')[:controller]
controller_klass = "#{controller_name}_controller".camelize.constantize
controller_klass._layout? ? controller_klass._layout : :application
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I'm running into a problem with the ActionController::Routing constant.  Apparently it no longer exists in the latest versions of rails 4.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30813115/2540204  Do you have a workaround?

Comment: Also, I'm getting an error `undefined method `_layout?`  Regarding the last line (if I just hardcode a controller into controller_klass).